# View.layout changes to default xml layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, viewgroup

In my app, I'm changing a layout location by doing this:

```
totalCommentLayout.layout(0, webviewHeight - buttomBtnsHeight - shadowHeight, width, webviewHeight);
```

The change is happening but then it changes back to the layout described in the `XML` file.
Why is that happening and how can I persist that change in location of the layout?

Comment: After what action does it return to the initial state. When you say "but them it changes back ..." it's not clear aftet what action or whatever this happens.

Comment: progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
This item is not in the layout.